# Задание запроса для Вики

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars') 
print(response.text) 
url='https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
headers = {'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'} 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
d = pq(url)
p = d("td")
print(p.text())
```

Этот код работает по прямо заданой ссылке. Нужно улучшить код до состаяния: Пользователь вводит слово - получает информацию с вики.
*Нельзя использовать библиотеку вики*

Comment: Делать запрос введенного слово в гугл +wiki и парсить 1ую ссылку

Comment: можно пожалуйста пример кода?

Comment: Можно делать запрос на такой адрес `https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=текст`, потом результат парсить

Comment: да, эту проблему решил. Есть еще одна: в выводе программа выводит гипер ссылки. Например: читать продолжение в источнике. Можно ли с помощью bf4 убрать все ссылки со страницы и вывести только текст?

Answer (score 1):

Делаем запрос:

```
# Запрашиваем пользователя или сами вводим что нужно найти
user_input = input( 'Search:' )

# Запрос
for_search = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=' + user_input
```

Дальше парсим по переменной "for_search". Можете использовать BeautifulSOUP буквально 10 минут на изучение парсинга.

Comment: В for_search вы просто кладете адрес, никакого запроса не происходит.

Comment: Это адрес который надо парсить

Answer (score 0):

> Есть еще одна: в выводе программа выводит гипер ссылки. Например:
>   читать продолжение в источнике. Можно ли с помощью bf4 убрать все
>   ссылки со страницы и вывести только текст?

Можно. А еще проще установить библиотеку [html-sanitizer](https://pypi.org/project/html-sanitizer/), которая сможет это сделать.